# Symfony3 CollectionType, Data returns as null

Tags: php, symfony

I have little problem creating collectiontype with symfony..

I have tried to follow multiple tutorial,like
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html or
http://toni.uebernickel.info/2012/03/15/an-example-of-symfony2-collectiontype-form-field-prototype.html..

but always with same result.

`$tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();` returns null.

I'm able to generate add/remove link and indexing is working aswell, but getting data into controller...

Am I missing something important or doing something wrong? Hope someone can help me out or give tip(s).

what I currently have

**Task entity**

```
 /**  
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="task",
 cascade={"persist", "remove"})  
 * /  protected $tags;
```

**Tag entity**

```
 /**  
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="tags")  
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")  
 * / 
 protected $task;
```

**TaskType**

```
->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
'entry_type' => TagType::class,
'allow_add' => true,
'allow_delete' => true,
'prototype_name' => '__tag__name__',))
```

**TagType**

```
$builder->add('name', TextType::class, array()));
```

**Macro**

```
{% macro widget_prototype(widget, remove_text) %}
   {% if widget.vars.prototype is defined %}
      {% set form = widget.vars.prototype %}
      {% set name = widget.vars.prototype.vars.name %}
   {% else %}
      {% set form = widget %}
      {% set name = widget.vars.full_name %}
   {% endif %}

   <div data-content="{{ name }}">
      <a class="btn-remove" data-related="{{ name }}">{{ remove_text }}</a>
       {{ form_widget(form) }}
   </div>

{% endmacro %}
```

**Twig**

```
<div id="post_tags" data-prototype="{{ _self.widget_prototype(form.tags, 'Remove tag')|escape }}">
 {% for widget in form.tags.children %}
     {{ _self.widget_prototype(widget, 'Remove tag') }}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
<a class="btn-add" data-target="post_tags">Add tag</a>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add[data-target]', function(event) {
        var collectionHolder = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target'));

        if (!collectionHolder.attr('data-counter')) {
            collectionHolder.attr('data-counter', collectionHolder.children().length);
        }

        var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');
        var form = prototype.replace(/__tag__name__/g, collectionHolder.attr('data-counter'));

        collectionHolder.attr('data-counter', Number(collectionHolder.attr('data-counter')) + 1);
        collectionHolder.append(form);

        event && event.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove[data-related]', function(event) {
        var name = $(this).attr('data-related');
        $('*[data-content="'+name+'"]').remove();

        event && event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and in **Controller**

```
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**

Task Entity setters and getters for tags

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function add(Tag $tag)
{
   $this->tags[] = $tag;
   return $this;
}

public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
   $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
}

public function getTags()
{
   return $this->tags;
}
```

Controller:

```
$task = new Task();
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isValid()){
    $tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();

     foreach($tags as $tag){
         //Here var_dump, echo, print, array_push etc tricks = empty
     }

     //Also without foreach var_dump = empty
}
```

Comment: Show your getters and setters (for tags) in the Task entity please.

Comment: could you post the whole controller or, at least, the relevant parts where you are trying to getting tags data?

Comment: updated question, getters and setters are generated with php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities - command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question with more details.

**To solve your problem right away, remember that Doctrine cascade only checks the owning side** (the side that has inversedBy - which in this case needs to stay where it is). So you should manually set the task a tag should have.

```
public function add(Tag $tag)
{
   $this->tags[] = $tag;
   $tag->task = $this;//added this line
   return $this;
}
```

---

**Assumption** - I believe that you haven't examined what you actually need. For the proper solution, I assume you need this functionality, one task has multiple tags, and a tag can be re-used across multiple tasks.

In this case:

**1. You're using a OneToMany relationship.** If you look at the first tutorial you refer to, **you need ManyToMany** (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

**2. Furthermore, you need a uni-directional ManyToMany.** Why? You are assigning tags inside a task, not the other way around. Plus, maybe you'll need to tag other entities.

For documentation on ManyToMany (uni-directional) have a look at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

---

**Task entity**

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @Assert\Valid
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tasks_tags",
 *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
 protected $tasks;
```

**Tag entity**

<s>protected $tasks;</s>

---

Note: When you delete tags from a task, and no other tasks are using a tag you deleted, the tag will be left as an "orphan". Doctrine doesn't work well with orphan removal on ManyToMany relationships, so you'll have to remove these orphans manually. Or you can leave the tag lying around, unused, to be added at a later time.

Comment: Finally! After sleepless week managed to find solution.. Still don't know why, but ajax call linked to submit button broke collectiontype..somehow.. I accept this as answer, eventhought didn't solve my problem but is well explained and improvement. :)